# Identifier Undefined C++ Even though I have the CPP, and Header file

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a `main.cpp` file and a bunch of other cpp files and header files that are included in the `main.cpp`. In the header files, I used `#indef`, `#define`, and `#endif` in the right place and I also included the header files in `main.cpp`. However, when I try to use a function I made in the main file, it goves me an error of "Identifier (function_name) undefined".

For ex:

```
//main.cpp
#include "example.h"

int main(){
foo();

//example.cpp
example::foo(){
     //code
}

//example.h
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

class example{
int foo();
}
#endif
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I doing things that aren't necessary?

Comment: `foo()` fails because `foo` is not defined.  Maybe you are mentally confusing `foo` with `example::foo`, those are different things.

Comment: And even in that case, `foo` is `private` to `example`, so invoking from `main` without (a) an object instance, and (b) friending of some degree, is impossible regardless. I think you need [a decent book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcpp%5D+book)

Answer (score 2):

The call `foo();` causes this error. To call the `example::foo` function, you need an object of type `example`. Like this :

```
int main() {
    example ex;
    ex.foo();
}
```

You must also make the `foo` method public, so that `main` can use it :

```
class example {
public:
    void foo();
};
```

**An example:**

Assume I have the following program :

```
void foo() { // #1
    // typetype codecode;
}

class Example {
public:
    void foo();
};

Example::foo() { // #2
    // typetype codecode;
}

int main() {
    Example ex;

    foo(); // #1 gets called
    ex.foo(); // #2 gets called on object ex
}
```

**More info:**

To understand this sort of thing better, you should learn about Object-Oriented Programming and classes. Explanations for OOP include these sites:

- [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)
- [tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_object_oriented.htm)

I'm sure you can find a LOT more sites explaining about OOP.